# Installing Windows 8.1 to new SSD while booted into Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, installation, ssd

I am nervous about proceeding through the install wizard past the "install" button, when I'm not sure what choices I'll be presented with, vs what assumptions the wizard makes for me.

**My situation:**

I want to install Windows 8.1 to a brand-new SSD drive. I do *NOT* need dual boot capability.

I don't have an install DVD, rather, I have an MSDN license, and I've downloaded the ISO.

I don't currently have a working disk drive to burn the iso to, so I want to run it while booted on my existing OS (windows 7), so I can't disconnect the HDD drive Win-7 is currently on.

I have formatted my SSD drive with MBR, but I haven't created a partition.

**My questions**

1) Will the install wizard provide me the choice of drive for installing the OS, or will it plunge ahead and install over windows-7 on my HDD?

2) Do I need to partition the new SSD drive (it's formatted MBR, but not yet partitioned), or can the install handle that?

3) Will I need to worry about which drive the boot partition is placed on, or will the install make sure it's on the new SSD for me?

4) Should I really wait until I can get this iso burned to a DVD, and install with the old HDD disconnected?

Comment: http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe   
There is a tool to convert the ISO to a USB stick.  Use any empty USB stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1   Yes it will offer you a choice.  However, the BIOS determines the first boot device and the windows installer will detect this and put a boot loader on that device no matter what else is on it.
  The best option is to disconnect all other HDD and SDD and install windows

Q2.  No you don't, the installer will handle that

Q3.  Unplug all other devices so the installer can't see the other drives.

Q4.  Use the link I provided in the comments to make a bootable USB and proceed that way.